# Ajax call to a Struts action doesn't return a response

Tags: ajax, jquery, struts

I'm trying to call an action servlet createLabel.do but looks like the action class is not being evoked. I used firebug to debug and it looks like this url is called  but receiving is no response.
Here's the javascript function:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function() {
          $("#createLabel").click(function() {
            $.ajax( {
              type: "POST",      
              url: "/createLabel.do",
              dataType: "json",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              data: { lab_no: $("#labNum").val(),accNum: $("#accNum").val(), label: $("#label").val() },
              success: function() {
                  alert("success");  
              }
            });
          });
    });

</script>
```

Here's my action class:

```
   public class CreateLabelAction extends Action{

public ActionForward execute (ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){


    String label = request.getParameter("label");

    String lab_no = request.getParameter("lab_no");
    String accNum = request.getParameter("accNum");

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    try {
        DB db = new DB(DB.DATA);
        Connection conn = db.GetConnection();
        String insertstmt = "update Info set label='"+label+"' where lab_no="+lab_no+" and accNum='"+accNum+"'";
        logger.info(insertstmt);

        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertstmt);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        pstmt.close();
        db.closeConn();

        logger.info("Label created successfully.");


    } catch (Exception e){
        logger.error("Error inserting label into Info" + e);
        request.setAttribute("error", "There was an error creating a label.");

    }

    logger.info("Label ="+label);
    label = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(label);
            return mapping.findForward("complete");
}

}
```

Here's the configuration in struts-config.xml:

```
 <action input="/labDi.jsp" name="LabelForm" path="/createLabel" scope="request" type="all.pageUtil.CreateLabelAction">
        <forward name="complete" path="/labDi.jsp" />
    </action>
```

Can someone please tell me why the action class is not being evoked? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of DOM element is `#createLabel`? Submit button, link, standard button, div, ...?

Comment: standard button: <input type="button" id="createLabel"  value="Create">

Comment: Is this button inside a form? What do you see in FireBug when you click on the button? Is an AJAX request being sent?

Comment: Try changing `dataType` to text, so you can find out if the problem is in getting a response or in getting a _valid_ response.

Comment: yes, it's inside a form. I see this "POST https://.../createLabelTDIS.do 200OK 19ms " with the Response tab blank

Comment: Be exceptionally careful accepting raw input like this - as this is written you're wide open to a SQL injection attack (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: there's another configuration file called web.xml in which all the <action> servlets are attached a ".do" extension.  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

Comment: Is there another way to specify the URL without using Struts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining behavior inside a method called `processRequest`, which Struts knows nothing about (unless it's a `DispatchAction` and you include a token parameter, which it isn't, and you don't).

Struts 1's default request handling method is called `execute`.

1.x: http://struts.apache.org/1.x/apidocs/org/apache/struts/action/Action.html

1.2: http://struts.apache.org/1.2.9/api/org/apache/struts/action/Action.html

1.1: http://struts.apache.org/1.1/api/org/apache/struts/action/Action.html

I don't know why you're expecting this to work. If you're creating an "action servlet" to handle normal Struts 1 requests, you're doing it wrong. Struts requests are handled by `Action`s (which you correctly subclass) in all but the most unusual situations.

The action servlet captures requests intended for Struts and uses the appropriate Struts request processor to look up and invoke the request's action. (Along with other related housekeeping chores.)

I'd recommend checking out some Struts 1 tutorials or documentation, if you really need to work with it.

Comment: ok I changed the processRequest method now. Please look at the changed code. it's still not working.

Comment: @Sapphire Still not the correct signature. You need to include your action mapping configmas well.

Comment: as in? I included the forward name "complete" in struts-config.xml as shown above...if that's what you mean.

Comment: @Sapphire You'd also need to make sure that whatever your form definition is is valid, although you completely ignore it in the action.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot! that did the trick, the missing form definition. it works now. phew!

Comment: The links are broken, can you fix it please??

Comment: @EmanueleGiarlini  The S1 docs are no longer online but may be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

//Here is the working ajax code, which sends request to struts action class .

```
function userExists(userid){
            var exists = false;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "./searchUser.do",
                    data: "userid=" + userid,
                    success: function(response){
                        exists = true;
                    },
                    error: function(e){
                        alert('Error: ' + e);
                    }
                });
            return exists;
            }
```

//Good Luck..

Hari